# How to send javascript array to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of javascript obejcts. I want to send this array to server. I tried :

```
JSON.stringify(jObectArray);
```

But at server side i am getting the empty array. How can i send it to server successfully ?

Comment: We can't see your array... **edit:** in fact we can't see how you're sending it either...

Comment: If you're using jQuery, try this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: More information is needed: the unknowns at present are (a) the contents of `jObjectArray` and (b) what the server is doing.

Comment: You didnt specify `type` in ajax (`get` or `post`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing **any** of your code:

```
var arr = ["one","two","three"];
arr = JSON.stringify(arr);
$.ajax({
  url: "something.something",
  data: {
    theArray: arr
  },
  success: function(data) {
    //success
  }
});
```

**EDIT:**
*What does your array look like...?*

Comment: You didnt specify 'type' in ajax ('get' or 'post')

Answer (score 1):

You should make:

```
$.ajax({
   url :'urltoserver',
   data: { myArray : jObectArray },
   dataType: 'JSON'
 });
```

Comment: No doubt you'll have your answer accepted... fickle SO users... :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   url :'urltoserver',
   data: {'yourarray':JSON.stringify(jObectArray)},
   dataType: 'JSON',
   type:"POST"
 });
```

at server

```
print_r($_POST['yourarray']);
```